# WPF how expose own object to other window

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this problem. I create two instaces of my classes in main window. An I need create other slave window in code behind and in this window I need consume method of objects created in main window.

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    //internal MyInterface1 MyObject1;
    //internal MyInterface2 MyObject2;

    internal MyClass1 MyObject1;
    internal MyClass2 MyObject2;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //create instances
        MyObject1 = new MyClass1();

        MyObject2 = new MyClass2();
    }

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        //in this window I neew consume some method and propertie of MyObject1 and MyObject1
        //my temporary solution is:
        var slaveWindow = new SlaveWindow(MyObject1, MyObject2);
    }

}
```

Can exist suitable solution, thank you.

Comment: This would work fine.  What's the problem?

Comment: I agree, your current solution seems perfectly fine to me as well.

Comment: Oki, I am begginer in C#, I'm not sure, so I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your "temporary" solution. I'd do it the same way.

Alternatively, you could publicly expose the two objects and then pass the `MainWindow` to the `SlaveWindow`:

```
class MainWindow : ...
{
    public MyClass1 MyObject1 { get; private set; }
    public MyClass1 MyObject2 { get; private set; }

    ...
    var slaveWindow = new SlaveWindow(this);
    ...
}

class SlaveWindow : ...
{
    public SlaveWindow(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        mainWindow.MyObject1.SomeMethod();
        mainWindow.MyObject2.SomeMethod();
    }
}
```

Whichever solution is preferable probably depends on the nature of your two objects. But I think it's fairly safe to say that your current solution is just fine.